# Open an Excel htm URL via iFrame in a separate browser

Tags: excel, url, iframe, wiki

I have some URLs in an Excel file which I have saved as a .htm (webpage) file.  I then view these in a browser via our wiki (MediaWiki).  This is done using an iFrame embedded in the wiki page.

So, just for clarity, the link is in a htm file viewed via an iFrame in a wiki page.

When I click on that link, it opens inside the iFrame.  What I want is for it to open in a new browser window.  (This should be the user's default browser since some use Internet Explorer and some Firefox.)

The final twist is that some users have Windows XP and some Solaris.

Following the first answer I should clarify: I use Insert -> Hyperlink to add the URL to text in a cell (in Excel).

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Mitchel's advice and opened the .htm file in Notepad++.  Then I changed the hyperlink code directly, resulting in something like this:

```
  <td height=17 class=xl24 style='height:12.75pt'><a
  href="<full URL>" target='_blank'>Direct
  Popup</a></td>
```

This opens the target, as he says, in a separate window.

When I opened the .htm file in Excel, I could not see target='_blank'.  This confirms what Mitchel said - it (unfortunately) does not support this.  =:-(

So, just to be clear:

before:

```
<a href="<url> > Direct Popup</a>
```

after (direct editing in Notepad++):

```
<a href="<url> target='_blank'> Direct Popup</a>
```

replacing `<url>` with the full URL path.

Oh, and Notepad (not just ++) probably works fine as well...

Comment: Please see also this wiki Q&A forum in start up phase: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wiki-edit

Answer (score 1):

Native MS Excel does not appear to support the the definition of `target='_blank'` on hyperlinks.  However, if you are generating the HTML/Excel file yourself you could add `target="_blank"` to all anchor tags and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thx for the quick reply.  How can I add that?  By default I use Insert -> Hyperlink to the text in a cell.  (I guess I should have mentioned that in the question.)

Comment: Yes, if you are using native MS Excel, you CANNOT input the value from what I can tell.

MS Excel can open regular HTML files as documents, and doing that you can control the link a bit better.